# Does the scp command on mac not respect the -l (limit) option?

Tags: scp

I'm fiddling with `scp` on mac and it *seems* to me like the `-l` option doesn't work; though I'm also (perhaps more) open to the idea that I'm just misunderstanding or misusing something. I'm not trying to solve a problem that requires limiting the bandwidth of a transfer so I don't need alternative suggestions, I'm just curious what's going on with my attempt to use this specific option. Looking for dis/confirmation that this is the behaviour other's are seeing and/or an explanation of what's wrong with my attempt.

I made a 10K file then tried to `scp` it to `localhost:<file>` with a limit of 1Kb/s thinking it should take ~80 seconds but the output of `scp` shows a transfer speed higher than 1Kb/s and the command completes effectively immediately.

[image: man scp output for -l option]

```
xy@xyz exploring-scp % man scp | grep -B1 Limits
    -l limit. 
        Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.
```

[image: sh commands I used]

```
src=$(mktemp)                                           
cat /dev/random | head -c 10240 > $src                  
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -l 1 $src localhost:/tmp/random.bin
```

My first thought was that maybe it's being "smart" and seeing localhost and skipping the network and therefore skipping with bandwidth limit; but the same thing happens both if I use the explicit IP for localhost, and also if I try to `scp` the file from a docker container back to the mac host.

I'm also fairly confident I've used the `-l` flag successfully on linux even when copying to/from localhost. (I was fiddling with it a little while ago on linux but it's not convenient right now for me to access a linux machine to try it on).

```
MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `scp` man page is pretty bare bones, but `wget` and `rsync` both provide this capability and are a bit more verbose on the subject.

`man wget` will tell you:

> Note that Wget implements the limiting by sleeping the appropriate amount of time after a network read that took less time than specified by the rate.
> Eventually this strategy causes the TCP transfer to slow down to approximately the specified rate.  However, it may take some time for this balance to be
> achieved, so don't be surprised if limiting the rate doesn't work well with very small files.

`man rsync` says:

> Rsync writes data over the socket in blocks, and this option both limits the size of the blocks that rsync writes, and tries to keep the average transfer
> rate  at  the requested limit.  Some burstiness may be seen where rsync writes out a block of data and then sleeps to bring the average rate into compliance.

I can't say for sure that either of these are the case with `scp`'s internals but I have had success applying rate limits to particularly large files.